# Colocar Macro a interagir com MsgBox automática

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou a tentar colocar uma macro a dar enter numa `MsgBox` automática, quando abre um ficheiro.

O que acontece é que ele abre o ficheiro, mas não faz nada. só após eu dar ok na msgbox é que ele ativa o comando de espera.
Alguém tem ideias para resolver?

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
"C:\Users\i37216\Desktop\Ficheiros Base e Outros\Cateteres\Bloco_operacional.xlsm"
waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + 5
Application.Wait waitTime
Application.SendKeys "{Enter}"
```

Comment: Olá, seu código foi formatado para uma melhor aparência. Caso queira, é possível editar a postagem. Para isso basta clicar no botão [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/531081/edit). Também removi mensagens de cumprimentos [saiba o motivo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/38/como-se-portar-ao-perguntar-responder).

Answer (score -1):

Olá, Ricardo!

O ideal é que você apresentasse o *print* da janela que abre, pois o conteúdo dela é relevante. Ela pode ser, por exemplo:

1. Um alerta do Excel (por exemplo, "O arquivo contém macros; tem certeza de que deseja executá-lo?");
2. Um erro em tempo de execução do VBA, embora não me pareça ser o caso;
3. Uma `msgbox` de um scrip VBA da planilha que você está abrindo.

Como eu não sei qual é o caso, vou dar uma solução que resolverá duas dessas possibilidades.

Se for um erro alerta do excel, você pode desativá-lo utilizando a propriedade `Application.DisplayAlerts` antes de abrir seu arquivo, mas recomendo não esquecer de reativá-la depois:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\...etc...\Bloco_operacional.xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Se for um erro em tempo de execução do VBA, você pode mandar o VBA rodar a despeito do erro usando o `On Error`, que configura o Error Handler do VBA:

```
On Error Resume Next ' Significa: ao encontrar um erro, ignore e prossiga
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\...etc...\Bloco_operacional.xlsm"
On Error GoTo 0 ' Significa: ao encontrar um erro, apresente o comportamento padrão de exibir e perguntar.
```

Por fim, você pode juntar as duas coisas sem problemas:

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\...etc...\Bloco_operacional.xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0
```

Pela sua pergunta e pelo arquivo que você pretende abrir ser um .xlsm, creio que a mensagem seja um alerta do excel, avisando que você vai abrir um arquivo com macros, oriundo da internet, etc, portanto, você resolveria com o `Application.DisplayAlerts`. Espero ter ajudado.